# запуск JavaScript в VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, windows-11

Windows. У меня есть Node.js и расширение CodeRunner, но код не запускается (или между строками со скрина вылезает кракозябра), хотя в туториале, который я смотрю, все сработало сразу. Я знаю, что здесь были вопросы с той же проблемой, но я буквально впервые начинаю этим заниматься и из-за незнакомой терминологии не могу понять шаги, которые предлагают в ответах. Будет очень хорошо, если кто-то уделит немного своего времени, чтобы расписать понятным языком, что надо сделать и можно ли это вообще исправить простым и быстрым способом.

[image: vsCode]

Comment: `console.log(3 + 2)` не работает?

Comment: То есть Вы буквально написали код, который не отображает ничего, и ждёте чуда?)

Comment: Предлагаю начать читать учебник, если не понятна терминология и не знаете основ языка: https://learn.javascript.ru

Answer (score 0):

1. Не 1 + 2 а `console.log(1 + 2)`
2. У вас не сохранен файл, Code Runner не понимает что ему запускать. Создайте файл, например index.js и туда уже запишите то что я указал в первом пункте. Далее пробуйте запустить.